# Get JSON and Parse it in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, get

I am getting json file from url with httpget request. Then, I want to print all tags that comes from json to the screen. I use this code for doing that however, I couldnot get in this way. Can you help me?

**Swift 3 code:**

```
let url:URL = URL(string: "https://api.hurriyet.com.tr/v1/articles...deleted...")!
let session = URLSession.shared

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    (data, response, error) in

    guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
    }

    let dataString =  String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    for tags in data{
        for tag in tags["Tags"]{
            print(tag)
        }
    }


}

task.resume()
```

**Example json output and dataString variable's output also:**

> "[{"Tags":["fırat","kalkanı
>   operasyonu","gazetehaberleri"]},{"Tags":["yüksek
>   yargı","adliye","gazetehaberleri"]},{"Tags":["foo","Hüseyin Avni
>   Mutlu","Hüseyin Çapkın","gazetehaberleri"]}]"

Comment: You need to parse the json string and convert it to a dictionary.

There are some libraries for parsing json (you can search on github) and I think there's also a builtin parser in Foundation

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: I couldn't convert the json into dictionary, can you help me? @LeoDabus

Comment: Okay, I have handled it, but, how can I get the Tags? Because cannot get them like jsonParsed["Tags"] etc... @LeoDabus

Comment: use swiftyJson to parse json easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First just a few notes about your code. Casting a URLRequest as URLRequest is redundant. You need to use JSONSerialization jsonObject with data method to parse your json data into an array of dictionaries:

```
let jsonString = "[{\"Tags\":[\"fırat\",\"kalkanı operasyonu\",\"gazetehaberleri\"]},{\"Tags\":[\"yüksek yargı\",\"adliye\",\"gazetehaberleri\"]},{\"Tags\":[\"foo\",\"Hüseyin Avni Mutlu\",\"Hüseyin Çapkın\",\"gazetehaberleri\"]}]"

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

let dictionaries = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [[String:Any]] ?? []

for dict in dictionaries {
    let tags = dict["Tags"] as? [String] ?? []

    for tag in tags {
        print(tag)  // fırat
                    // kalkanı operasyonu
                    // gazetehaberleri
                    // yüksek yargı
                    // adliye
                    // gazetehaberleri
                    // foo
                    // Hüseyin Avni Mutlu
                    // Hüseyin Çapkın
                    // gazetehaberleri
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json output response is in format Array of Dictionary `[[String: Any]]`

So the simple way to parse it is

```
do {
    // parse from data to array of dictionaries
    if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
        print(parsedData)
    }
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Then what can I do for getting all Tags? Because print(parsedData["Tags"]) is making an error like: cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: @CrisAngelordan add your current code `for tags in parsedData`

Comment: Okay but it can get only first Tags part, second, third Tags cannot get with this loop. I tried that: for dict in parsedData { for parsed in dict["Tags"] { print(parsed) } }. However, there is an error: type 'Any?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'  @LeoDabus

Comment: add this `for parsed in dict["Tags"] as! [String] { // print }` to make it as array of String